# Start flask from Powershell

Tags: powershell, flask

Does somebody have any idea how to start my flask server in the morning with Powershell?

I have a powershell function but it creates a loop :(

```
function flask{
    Write-Host "Starting flask"

    conda activate chk_req
    cd $codepath\projects\chk_req
    $env:FLASK_APP='run3.py'
    flask run
    Write-Host " > FINISHED"
}
```

Comment: Probably because you gave the function the name `flask`. If you wish to keep that name try something like `flask.exe run`.

Comment: What @Vivere says. You might also be able to get around it by changing `flask run` to `python -m flask run`